# How to make API call, fetch the data and display on webpage using twit npm package

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter

I am new to web-development, and I am trying to fetch top 10 trending hashtags from twitter and display on web page. I have below `index.html` and `website.js` script. For making API call, I am using `twit npm` package.When I run `index.html` file from VS-Code, Under console log I am receiving an error that says "`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/twit/lib/twitter.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`. I am currently not sure what could be the issue ? To my understanding it has to do with package., but not sure. Any help on this issue will be appreciated!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Twitter Trending Hashtags</title>
   <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Trending Hashtags</h1>
        <ul id="trendingHashtags">
            <!-- Trending hashtags will be added dynamically here -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type='module' src="./website.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Website.js**

```
import Twit from './node_modules/twit/lib/twitter.js';
const apikey = 'API_KEY';
const apisecretkey = 'AP_SECRET_KEY';
const accesstoken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';
const accesstokensecret = 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET';

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: apikey,
  consumer_secret: apisecretkey,
  access_token: accesstoken,
  access_token_secret: accesstokensecret,
  timeout_ms: 60*1000,
  strictSSL: true
});

var params = { id: '23424977' };

T.get('trends/place', params, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  var trends = data[0].trends;
  var html = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < trends.length; i++) {
    var trend = trends[i];
    var name = trend.name;
    var tweetVolume = trend.tweet_volume || 'N/A';

    html += `<div>
      <p>Name: ${name}</p>
      <p>Tweet Volume: ${tweetVolume}</p>
    </div>`;
  }
  var hashtagsContainer = document.getElementById('hashtags-container');
  hashtagsContainer.innerHTML = html;

   //console.log(html);
});
```

**Update**

After running the suggestion provided by SO user.I am still receiving an error under Console log of Google Chrome that says " T`he requested module './node_modules/twit/lib/twitter.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`". *All the Chrome extensions have been disabled as well.*

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be with the way you are importing the twit module in your website.js file. Try way to import the twit module is as follows:

```
import Twit from 'twit';
```

Additionally, you need to correct the id attribute in your HTML file. Currently, it's set as 'hashtags-container', but it should be 'trendingHashtags' to match the ID used in the JavaScript code.

try this code:
html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Twitter Trending Hashtags</title>
    <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Trending Hashtags</h1>
        <ul id="trendingHashtags">
            <!-- Trending hashtags will be added dynamically here -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type='module' src="./website.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

website.js

```
import Twit from 'twit';
const apikey = 'API_KEY';
const apisecretkey = 'AP_SECRET_KEY';
const accesstoken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';
const accesstokensecret = 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET';

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: apikey,
  consumer_secret: apisecretkey,
  access_token: accesstoken,
  access_token_secret: accesstokensecret,
  timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,
  strictSSL: true,
});

var params = { id: '23424977' };

T.get('trends/place', params, function (err, data, response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  var trends = data[0].trends;
  var html = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < trends.length; i++) {
    var trend = trends[i];
    var name = trend.name;
    var tweetVolume = trend.tweet_volume || 'N/A';

    html += `<div>
      <p>Name: ${name}</p>
      <p>Tweet Volume: ${tweetVolume}</p>
    </div>`;
  }
  var trendingHashtagsContainer = document.getElementById('trendingHashtags');
  trendingHashtagsContainer.innerHTML = html;
});
```

Comment: ..Thank now I updated the code per your suggestion but unfortunately I am receiving an error under Google Chrome Console that says "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "twit". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"" This was the reason I switched my import code to "./node_modules/twit/lib/twitter.js". Unfortunatley, it is still throwing an error even if I try with ./node_modules/twit/lib/twitter.js. The error reads " The requested module './node_modules/twit/lib/twitter.js' does not provide an export named 'default'"